# По-моему, ты, это говоря, очень не прав / неправ

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> По-моему, ты, это говоря, очень не прав / неправ.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%2C+%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *По-моему, ты, это говоря, **очень неправ**.*

**Пояснение**

1. В общем случае существуют две формы написания: ***не прав и неправ.***
   Утвердительный вариант обозначен в словаре РАН, и он является основным.

**Дополнительный** признак: усилительное наречие "очень", оно не используется при отрицании.

2. Раздельное написание применяется  **в двух случаях:** противопоставление и усиление отрицания: *ты **не прав**, а ошибаешься; ты **нисколько** не прав.*

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

1. Русский орфографический словарь:
   **неправ,** -ава, -аво.
2. Большой толковый словарь

**НЕПРАВЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -прав, -а, -о. 1. **Поступающий,** говорящий ошибочно, неправильно. Человек, н. в своих действиях. Вы неправы, отказавшись подписать заявление. Считать друг друга неправыми. 2. **Высок. Несправедливый**; противоречащий праву (1.П.; 3 зн.). Н. суд. Н-ое обвинение. * Неправ твой, о Небо, святой приговор! (Лермонтов).

3. Ответы **справочной службы**

№ 216318
Скажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях пишется ***не прав*** и ***неправ?***

ОТВЕТ.  При противопоставлении правильно: ***не прав***, без противопоставления: ***неправ.***

4. **[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77) пункт 6 и 9.**

Пункт 6. Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает **наречие меры и степени** (весьма, крайне, очень, почти или наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица не с прилагательным всегда пишется слитно: весьма некрасивый поступок; крайне неуместный выпад; очень неудачное выступление; почти незнакомый текст; в высшей степени неразборчивый почерк.

Пункт 9. С **краткими** формами прилагательных частица не пишется в основном так же, как с полными.

**ПРИМЕРЫ (Нацкорпус)**

Это все найденные примеры, вариант используется не часто.

1. Светлана Скарлош, Ольга Цыбульская. Покаяние оптом и в розницу // «Русский репортер», № 28 (156), 22-29 июля 2010.
   — Он просил зачитать, так что послушайте: «Любимая, ласковая, милая моя Настенька, — с чувством декламирует Наталья, — **я был очень неправ.**
2. Ю. А. Кривулина (Хордикайнен). Дневник (1960).
   А Ким вчера **был очень неправ, груб.**
3. И. В. Омулевский. Острожный художник // Художественный журнал, 1882. — И, по-моему, Миша вчера был **очень неправ к нему,** — прибавила она еще тише, как бы поясняя свою мысль.
4. Ф. Ф. Тютчев. На скалах и долинах Дагестана (1903).
   До сих пор я считал людей виноватыми, а себя кругом правым, а теперь вижу, что хотя люди и действительно во многом против меня виновны, но и **я очень и очень не прав.**

**P. S.**  Я дополнила уже принятый ответ, так как он не соответствует нужному **КАЧЕСТВУ.** Могу отметить следующие **неточности.**

```
1. С краткими формами прилагательных частица НЕ 
пишется в основном так же, как с полными.  Для форм  
прав/не прав  нет соотнесенности  с рядом, который 
рассматривается особым образом:  не рад; не должен, 
не горазд; не прав.
2. Не указано влияние усилительного наречия «очень».
3. Не указано влияние противопоставления на выбор  
раздельной формы, которое является основным.  
Указано только  отрицание положительного признака.
4. Не указаны источники: словари  и ссылки на нужное 
правило.
```

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от контекста.
Есть правило: НЕ пишется РАЗДЕЛЬНО с прилагательными в краткой форме, не имеющими соответствующих полных форм (не рад; не должен, не горазд; не прав)

Если писать слитно, то слово «неправ» обретает смысл несправедливости, неправедности.

Чаще всего встречается написание «не прав» как отрицание положительного признака.

Comment: Оба варианта верны на самом деле. При утверждении слитно, при отрицании раздельно. Так Грамота не оаз в своих ответах говорила. Лучше, действительно, слитно написать.

Comment: @Максим (1) Грамота для раздельного написания определяет отрицание при противопоставлении как основной признак для "не прав". gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/216318 (2) По Розенталю  наречие "очень" задает слитное   написание "неправ" практически однозначно.