# Она была очень-преочень нерада / не рада

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я был так неправ / не прав!

> Она была очень-преочень нерада / не рада, когда я ей это сказал.

Comment: Повтор темы  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478564/По-моему-ты-это-говоря-очень-не-прав-неправ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Оба варианта** возможны: *Я был так **неправ / не прав**!*

**[Карта слов](https://en.kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2)**

*Ты так **неправ.** You are so wrong.*

*Я был так **неправ.** I was so wrong about that.*

*Саттер, ты так **не прав.** Sutter, you are so wrong.*

*Я был так **не прав.** I have done you a terrible wrong.*

Наречие ***так*** [в словаре Ефремовой](https://%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20I%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87.%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82.%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%201.%20%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5.%202.%20%D0%92%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.%203.%20%D0%92%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5,%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8;%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE.%20%20%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%20https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA) имеет **усилительное** значение, но возможно усиления как отрицания, так и утверждения.

2. *Она была  очень-преочень **не рада,** когда я ей это сказал.*

**Всегда** пишется раздельно: ***не рад.*** Наречие степени **нежелательно** применять для усиления отрицания.

А  другие **усилительные** слова?  Они **редко** используются (в Нацкорпусе нашлось 4 примера, но с усилением **ОТРИЦАНИЯ**):

*Элька теперь понимала, что господин герцог **вовсе не рад** тому, что она нашлась...*

*А я, может быть, **вовсе не рад!***

Answer (score 2):

[Отрицание «не» пишется раздельно с прилагательными, употребляющимися только в краткой форме: не рад, не должен, не горазд.](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-4%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%C2%A7146)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*Я был так не прав!*

*Она была очень-преочень не рада, когда я ей это сказал.*